# Load a UIViewController as main controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just created an empty iOS project and added a UIViewController with a nib file. This should load my main view.

How do I tell my application to load a certain UIViewController as main view? Do I have to set it on the app delegate or somewhere in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app delegate have a variable for the controller....

```
MyViewController myController;
```

Then you want...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    myController = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:myController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

You can also hook this up via Interface Builder, but the above is how you would do it in code.